# Selected value not updated when Binding a list of Enum values as ItemSource in C# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to bind the selected value to a string property to a combo box in which the itemsource is binded with a list of Enum values.But the selected value is not displayed in combo box.

```
public enum FilterOperation
{
    Includes,
    NotIncludes,
    Equals,
    NotEquals        
}

// Adding the Values to the list in constructor 
StringFilterList.Add(FilterOperation.Includes);
StringFilterList.Add(FilterOperation.NotIncludes);
StringFilterList.Add(FilterOperation.Equals);
StringFilterList.Add(FilterOperation.NotEquals);

// Initially assigning first value as default value.
FilterSelected = StringFilterList.FirstOrDefault().ToString();


// XAML.
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"                          
          ItemsSource="{Binding StringFilterList}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding FilterSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
          />
```

But the selected value is not listed even the list is loaded.

Please try to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the `SelectedValue` property must match the type of values in the `ItemsSource`.

Change the type of your `FilterSelected` property to `FilterOperation` and set the value to an enum value:

```
// Initially assigning first value as default value.
FilterSelected = FilterOperation.Includes;
//or:
//FilterSelected = StringFilterList.FirstOrDefault();
```

Or you will have to use a value converter to convert between `string` and `FilterOperation`: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/. WPF won't do this conversion for you automatically.